# How to Install PySpark on Snowflake to execute PySpark in snowflake python sheet

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I understand that Snowflake works with both Python and Spark with Snowpark in Python sheets. This allows developers to leverage Pyspark capabilities in the platform. The Snowflake Connector for Spark (“Spark connector”) brings Snowflake into the Apache Spark ecosystem, enabling Spark to read data from, and write data to, Snowflake.

The issue is that I would to execute PySpark from a Python worksheet in SnowFlake. Therefore, I believe I have to install the PySpark package. Can someone confirm that to be case? And if that is the case, is there any documentation available on the process?

Answer (score 0):

[Snowpark for Python](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/index) and [Spark Connector for Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-overview) are two different libraries.

While Snowpark is integrated nowadays into Snowflake server side and can be used in Python Worksheets, the same is `NOT` applicable to Spark Connector.

Spark Connector  enables using Snowflake as an Apache Spark (and therefore the PySpark shell) data source, similar to other data sources (PostgreSQL, HDFS, S3, etc.) and is only a client side library but cannot be used in Snowflake on Python Worksheets.

Comment: thanks for getting in touch. If what you say is correct. Can you let me know how I would go about installing PySpark as a package on SnowFlake?

Comment: You can't install PySpark since there won't be any Apache Spark on the server side, so even if you could it would not help. You can integrate Spark Connector with an existing Apache Spark if you have one.